# Separate faces of a 3D matrix using a minimal cost intersection/slice/separation

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, networkx

Suppose I have a (**n x n x n**) 3D numpy matrix filled with costs as the elements.
How do I find the set of (**n x n**) elements that minimize the cost of completely separating the front slice from the back slice?
That is, (for example, on the x-axis) if my front (the source) is [0, :, :] and my back (the sink) is [n-1, :, ;], how do I completely separate them assuming 26-connected elements?

Example if left and right are my faces:
[image]

I tried using *networkx* but unfortunately you can only select one element as source and one as sink, instead of selecting an entire (**n x n**) slice (Which would be perfect for me).

Comment: Shouldn't purple slice be `n x n` square? If I understand correctly only such squares, perpendicular to axis will can be considered as possibilities to separate two faces. If not, I think explanation lacks something.

Comment: Yes, normally that's correct. However in my case I consider a 26-connected structure, meaning that any cube in the neighbourhood of another (one of the 26 adjacent cubes including diagonals) is considered 'closed' and thus contributes to separating the two faces.